# T-SQL show records that are due to expire in two months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I show records that are due to expire in two months?

I have tried using `DATEADD` but I appear to have the logic code incorrect.

```
GETDATE() >= DATEADD(MONTH,-2, cycles.[NEXT-DATE])
```

Any code on how I can do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Show some sample data that has rows you want to select and rows that you do not want to select. That will make the logic much easier to identify.

Comment: What was wrong with the logic you had? (Although I would recommend putting the `DATEADD` function around `GETDATE()` instead to maintain SARGAbility.)

Comment: `WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), [NEXT-DATE]) = 60` is helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Your code gives you records that have expiry date equal 2 months or more. You should change your condition. Draw a time line to visualize it (it's easier then to understand how it should look like).

```
GETDATE() >= DATEADD(MONTH,-2, cycles.[NEXT-DATE])
and GETDATE() <= cycles.[NEXT-DATE] --checking if date is in the future
```

Comment: I still recommend not wrapping `cycles.[NEXT-DATE]` in `DATEADD`; it should be around `GETDATE()`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be sth like this

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, GETDATE()), cycles.[NEXT-DATE]) < 0
```

Comment: Sorry the requirement has changed to a quarter, can this be easily done?

Comment: Hi, 
In DATEADD(MONTH, 2, GETDATE()) , 2 is parameter, You can change it to whatever Your requirement is. Quarter = 3

Comment: Thanks @Jacek-Drodz